# How to solve the Sleeping Barbers analogy with multiple barbers in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, process, python-multithreading

I have a working solution for the Sleeping Barber operating system problem using python 2.7 and threading that works with a single barber and a certain amount of chairs. But I would like it to be able to work in a situation where there are multiple barbers, in the same way as there is multiple customers.

Here is my current solution with a single barber:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock, Event
import time, random
from sys import exit
lock = Lock()
customerIntervalMin = 5
customerIntervalMax = 15
haircutDurationMin = 3
haircutDurationMax = 15

class BarberShop:
        waitingCustomers = []
        threads=[]
        finishedCustomers = []

        def __init__(self, barber, numberOfSeats):
                self.barber = barber
                self.numberOfSeats = numberOfSeats

        def openShop(self):
                print 'Barber shop is opening'
                workingThread = Thread(target = self.barberGoToWork)
                workingThread.start()
                self.threads.append(workingThread)


        def barberGoToWork(self):
                while True:
                        lock.acquire()

                        if len(self.waitingCustomers) > 0 and len(self.finishedCustomers)< 5:
                                c = self.waitingCustomers[0]
                                del self.waitingCustomers[0]
                                lock.release()
                                self.barber.cutHair(c)
                                self.finishedCustomers.append(c)
                        elif  len(self.waitingCustomers)==0 and len(self.finishedCustomers)<5:
                                lock.release()
                                print 'Aaah, all done, {0} is going to sleep'.format(barber.name)
                                barber.sleeps()
                                print '{0} woke up'.format(barber.name)
                        elif len(self.waitingCustomers)==0 and len(self.finishedCustomers)==5:
                                lock.release()
                                print 'The barber shop is closed. Come back tomorrow.'
                                exit(0)


        def enterBarberShop(self, customer):
                lock.acquire()
                print '{0} entered the shop and is looking for a seat'.format(customer.name)

                if len(self.waitingCustomers) == self.numberOfSeats:
                        print 'Waiting room is full, {0} is leaving.'.format(customer.name)
                        lock.release()
                else:
                        print '{0} sat down in the waiting room'.format(customer.name)
                        self.waitingCustomers.append(c)
                        lock.release()
                        barber.wakeUp()

class Customer:
        def __init__(self, name):
                self.name = name

class Barber:
        def __init__(self, name):
                self.name = name

        barberEvent = Event()

        def sleeps(self):
                self.barberEvent.wait()

        def wakeUp(self):
                self.barberEvent.set()

        def cutHair(self, customer):
                self.barberEvent.clear()
                print '{0} is having a haircut done by {1}'.format(customer.name, self.name)
                randomHairCuttingTime = random.randrange(haircutDurationMin, haircutDurationMax+1)
                time.sleep(randomHairCuttingTime)
                print '{0} is done with {1}'.format(customer.name, self.name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        customers = []
        customers.append(Customer('Ken'))
        customers.append(Customer('Scott'))
        customers.append(Customer('Larry'))
        customers.append(Customer('Liam'))
        customers.append(Customer('Kieran'))

        barber = Barber('Mark')
        barberShop = BarberShop(barber, numberOfSeats=10)
        barberShop.openShop()

        while len(customers) > 0:
                c = customers.pop()
                barberShop.enterBarberShop(c)
                customerInterval = random.randrange(customerIntervalMin,customerIntervalMax+1)
                time.sleep(customerInterval)
```

I'm confused as to how to go about this. I originally thought it would be the same as the customers list inside the main where you would just append the class & the given name parameter into a list, use a loop to go through the list, pop each instance in the list & assign that to barber & keep the original `barberShop` definition in the main. But upon reflection that can't be right because that would just create 3 different threads with 10 seats each. So now I am unsure of how to solve the last part of this problem and while there is plenty of online implementations of this specific aspect of the problem in languages like Java & C but I don't have enough experience with those languages to even understand those solutions, let alone translate them into python & implement aspects of it in the solution above.

Is there any other way I can implement multiple barbers into this solution? Any help at all on this aspect of the problem or any suggestions for improvements that can be made to my solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
In general, you *should* have a focused idea of how to work the problem, some code to implement that idea, and a specific problem with that code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to design your system exactly as you've described in words: you instantiate three barbers, each of whom has full permissions on the *same* ten-chair waiting room.  This means that your mutex operations have to be hardy enough for 3 actors and 10 targets.  You also have to allow a new customer to wake up a sleeping barber, regardless of how many are asleep.

Think in terms of your barber states and your customer states.  Focus on each combination in turn, and design how the system should react.  Then, given those various actions (e.g. "customer wakes up barber", "barber moves customer to work chair"), decide how to allocate your methods to classes.

Does that help you get moving?

Comment: That is helpful. Could you just elaborate on what you mean by the mutex operations being hardy enough for the 3 actors and 10 targets? I've tested the code previously with the number of chairs being greater than & lesser than 10 as well as with multiple customers & I'm happy with how it operates but I'm just not sure how to go about actually defining the barbers. Is there any advice you would give to me specifically about instantiating the barbers? And would you agree that my previous idea of defining them in a similar way to the customers is a bad way of going about it?

Comment: You're asking for a personal tutorial on systems design; this is outside the stated Stack Overflow purposes on two counts.